# Sobrescribir rutas por defecto en sailsjs

Tags: javascript, sailsjs

Tengo un controllador llamado `UsersController` con el siguiente método:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res, next){
        Users.find({}, function(err, users){
            if(err) return next(err);
            if(!users) return next();

            res.json({"data": users});
        });
    },
}
```

El cual me entrega un `JSON` como este:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            name: "Jhon Doe",
            username: "jhon.doe",
            email: "jhon.doe@example.com",
            role: 1,
            logged: 0,
            status: 1,
            id: 1,
            createdAt: "2016-10-28T00:42:04.000Z",
            updatedAt: "2016-10-28T00:42:04.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Y en mi archivo `config/routes.js`

```
module.exports.routes = {
    'GET /users/GET_ALL': {
        controller: "UsersController",
        action: "index"
    }
}
```

Si accedo por ambas rutas `/users/` y `/users/GET_ALL/` puedo obtener el `JSON` mostrado arriba, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo obtenerlo (el `JSON`) solamente mediante la ruta `/users/GET_ALL/` y que al acceder por la otra `/users/` me mande un `error 404` o lo que sea que yo quiera mostrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la respuesta de Isaac Vega leí un poco más acerca del objeto `req` y encontré que tiene un `método` llamado `path` el cual me sirve para hacer la validación que quiero pues este mismo devuelve el `uri` que se encuentra luego del `host` entregado al darle un `sails lift` a la aplicación:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res, next){
        if(req.path == '/users/'){
            res.notFound();
        }else{
            Users.find({}, function(err, users){
                if(err) return next(err);
                if(!users) return next();

                res.json({"data": users});
            });
        }
    },
}
```

Así bien, si ingreso por `/users/` me devolverá un `error 404`, en cambio si ingreso por `/users/GET_ALL/` obtengo el `JSON` correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces un pedido HTTP de cualquier tipo (GET, POST, PUT, etc...) puedes verificar en node.js los headers del objeto que creaste req (el request del usuario, req.headers), y ver el tipo de peticion que se hizo. Puedes controlar con el modulo fs que si la peticion es sobre la ruta deseada, que envie el JSON, si no, que envie una pagina de error. Por ejemplo:
a

```
if(/*direccion incorrecta*/)
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/403.html", function(e, d) {
        if(e)
            return response.end("403 Forbiden");
        return response.end(d);
    });
else
    //retornar el JSON
```

al retornar response.end(d), le envias al cliente el contenido de la pagina 403.html que leiste, indicandole que no puede acceder a ese lugar. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido muy útil para solucionar mi problema.